# Error getting a json response from http request

Tags: php, json, symfony, curl

I am trying to get the response from an http request from the Hunter API.

The url is something like this :

```
https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-finder?domain=mydomain&api_key=myapikey&first_name=myfirstname&last_name=myname
```

And the response is something like this :

```
{
  "data": {
    "email": "emailfound@domain.tld",
    "score": 68,
    "domain": "domain.tld",
    "sources": [
      {
        "domain": "domain.tld",
        "uri": "http://somedomain.tld/",
        "extracted_on": "2017-04-04"
      }
    ]
  },
  "meta": {
    "params": {
      "first_name": "myfirstname",
      "last_name": "mylastname",
      "full_name": null,
      "domain": "domain.tld",
      "company": null
    }
  }
}
```

Here is what I am doing in my controller :

```
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    $response = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // return response
    $json = new JsonResponse();
    $datas = $json->setData($response);
    return json_encode($datas);
```

And here is what json_encode($datas) returns :

```
{"headers":{}}
```

I precise that I am working with Symfony3 and testing on my OVH serveur (Performance offer).

Any idea where does come from this response ? and why I am not getting the real response ? Thanks !

Comment: Do you have to use curl? You can get api results easier with `$json = file_get_contents($url);` from my experience

Comment: it's working perfectly ! and so much simple, thanks !

Comment: If anyone helped you, you should mark the answer as "correct" by clicking the checkmark to the left of their answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment,

Instead of using CURL (Which is a much harder system to deal with IMO), you should use `file_get_contents()` like so:

```
$json = file_get_contents($url);
$obj = json_decode($json,true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://api.hunter.io/v2/email-finder?domain=mydomain&api_key=myapikey&first_name=myfirstname&last_name=myname');
$data = json_encode($json,true)
var_dump($data);
```